# How to apply custom style for pagination in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, pagination

Can you help me to apply custom style for pagination in my WordPress website? Here's the code of html, I use bootstrap 4

https://jsfiddle.net/h51Lyt9c/

I tried this function which I got from wpbeginner, but it doesn't working!

```php
function b8ak_numeric_posts_nav() {

if( is_singular() ) return;

global $wp_query;

/** Stop execution if there's only 1 page */
if( $wp_query->max_num_pages <= 1 ) return;

$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
$max   = intval( $wp_query->max_num_pages );

/** Add current page to the array */
if ( $paged >= 1 ) $links[] = $paged;

/** Add the pages around the current page to the array */
if ( $paged >= 3 ) {
    $links[] = $paged - 1;
    $links[] = $paged - 2;
}

if ( ( $paged + 2 ) <= $max ) {
    $links[] = $paged + 2;
    $links[] = $paged + 1;
}

echo '<div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-5"><ul class="list-unstyled d-inline m-0">' . "\n";

/** Previous Post Link */
if ( get_previous_posts_link() )
    printf( '<li>%s</li>' . "\n", get_previous_posts_link() );

/** Link to first page, plus ellipses if necessary */
if ( ! in_array( 1, $links ) ) {
    $class = 1 == $paged ? ' class="blog-page__pagination list-inline-item border rounded-circle"' : '';

    printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ), '1' );

    if ( ! in_array( 2, $links ) )
        echo '<li class="blog-page__pagination list-inline-item border rounded-circle">…</li>';
}

/** Link to current page, plus 2 pages in either direction if necessary */
sort( $links );
foreach ( (array) $links as $link ) {
    $class = $paged == $link ? ' class="blog-page__pagination list-inline-item border rounded-circle"' : '';
    printf( '<li%s class="blog-page__pagination list-inline-item border rounded-circle"><a class="text-dark d-block px-3 py-2 text-decoration-none" href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $link ) ), $link );
}

/** Link to last page, plus ellipses if necessary */
if ( ! in_array( $max, $links ) ) {
    if ( ! in_array( $max - 1, $links ) )
        echo '<li>…</li>' . "\n";

    $class = $paged == $max ? ' class="blog-page__pagination list-inline-item border rounded-circle"' : '';
    printf( '<li%s class="blog-page__pagination list-inline-item border rounded-circle"><a class="text-dark d-block px-3 py-2 text-decoration-none" href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $max ) ), $max );
}

/** Next Post Link */
if ( get_next_posts_link() )
    printf( '<li class="blog-page__pagination list-inline-item border rounded-circle">%s</li>' . "\n", get_next_posts_link() );

echo '</ul></div>' . "\n";

}
```

Then I echoed the function in the archive.php page to show the pagination

```
<?php b8ak_numeric_posts_nav(); ?>
```

Actually I don't know where's the problem of applying my custom css style to WordPress pagination, can anyone help me to apply the custom style to pagination? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please, remove salutations. [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: Is this for your blog feed?  You want to put it in `index.php`